# A user can overload the default constructor of the class in java is this true or false?

Tags: java, constructor, overloading, default-constructor

For the code below I was able to overload the default constructor but according to the book JAVA OCA SE 8 by mala gupta this statement is false it says we cannot overload a default constructor any thoughts ?

```
package com.sandy.OCA_prep;


class App
{
    static
    {
        System.out.println("inside static block");
    }
    App(int a)
    {
        System.out.println("inside the integer overloaded constructor");
    }
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {  
      System.out.println("hello world");


      App app2=new App(5);

    }
}
```

Comment: I imagine what it means is that the default no-argument constructor no longer exists in your class because you added an explicit constructor.

Comment: So there is one statement and I quote "A user can overload the default constructor of the class" is it true or false

Comment: @sandeepnegi1996: if you **have** to have an answer, then it's "false", but the question is fundamentally flawed, so the answer won't be perfect either.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "overloading the  default constructor" is non-sensical:

- Overloading refers to having multiple methods with the same name but different parameters lists.
- The default constructor is the no-argument constructor that the compiler generates for you if you don't specify any other constructor. It has no arguments by definition.
- Since overloading requires different parameter lists and the default constructor by definition only has one possible parameter list (the empty one), these two concepts don't interact in a meaningful way.

You can *specify your own no-argument constructor* and thus stop the compiler from generating the default constructor, but I would not call that "overloading the default constructor".

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky question. By definition the default constructor is the constructor provided by the compiler when you do not include one. 
Let's say you write a class and then compile it. In the .class file that will be produced, you will see that there is a no-args constructor, even if you didn't include one in your code. That's the default constructor. 
However, as you write your own constructors, the default one will not be inserted by the compiler. Remember that the no-args constructor you write is not considered the default constructor.
So, technically speaking, the default constructor can never be overloaded.

Answer (score 0):

> I was able to overload the default constructor

No you weren't. There is no overloading here. Overloading refers to having two or more of the same method distinguishable by different parameter lists.

By declaring your own constructor, the default constructor - the implicit constructor which is used if you don't declare your own - is not applied.